# Component best practice. How to allow different methods of positioning for components

Tags: svelte

Lets say i have a reusable component that i want to place at an absolute position but i also want to allow it to be placed inside eg. flex-boxes. What is the intended workflow for this since i cannot easily pass styles to child components? I know i can use the
.parent :global(.child) pattern but this seems like an ugly way of solving the issue but the best i have found. I could also habitually wrap components inside style wrappers to give them absolute positions but this also seems like a blunt way of approaching it. I am thinking i might need to change my mindset on how to approach the problem so i am open to both specific feedback and feedback on how to approach thee issue in a different way.

This REPL demonstrates the issue
https://svelte.dev/repl/da3cd9b8b8f54cd7b0bfac958d1b938e?version=3.46.2

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue. Are you asking if you can conditionally absolute position a component?

Comment: I do not want the position to be defined by the component as i want it to be reusable in multiple different scenarios, so i'm thinking that the positioning should be provided by the parent instead of the component itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using a wrapper, using inline-styles does not seem like that big of an evil here. Positioning information is not something that usually requires lower specificity so it can be overridden.

For generic components like buttons I tend to apply the `$$restProps` which would also allow just setting `style`.

```html
<MyButton style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 40px;"/>
```

```html
<!-- MyButton.svelte -->
<button {...$$restProps}>
    MyButton
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like a better syntax to me. Although the docs do discourage the use of $$restProps, but i suspect for my current intentions it may suffice. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: If you know that you will need `style` you can also just export it manually.

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer, although for the record i would have preferred if svelte supported this more natively so styles could be declared in a more uniform manner. Again thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add a series of properties to your component to do so this is is not possible. And positioning itself is not really the task of the component is it ?

So your best options are doing the positioning from outside the component by wrapping the component. Or if you want allow the users to pass a css class to the component and apply it correctly, beware that this class still has to be marked as global of course.

Comment: I agree that positioning is not the task of the component, which is why i ask the question. This is why i feel there should be a better practice than having to wrap every component in a positioning element. I would expect something along the lines of this: 
<MyComponent style:position="absolute" style:left="12px"/>
Is this really regarded as a good practice:
<div style:position="absolute" style:left="12px">
<MyComponent/>
</div>

Comment: @JonSandström: The thing that is not best practice is probably the use of `position: absolute`, that should be used rarely if ever.

Comment: @ H.B Agreed, but i work with prototyping based on sketches which often require me to use this. And then rebuild when the design is more mature

Comment: @JonSandström: If you use that a lot you could create a separate component for it, e.g. `<Absolute x="12px">...</Absolute>`

Comment: @H.B Yes, I've considered this approach and it's still conceptually a wrapper element although maybe slightly more elegant. But perhaps there is no better solution currently. I also know there has been a large discussion regarding passing styles to child components and thought maybe there has been some advances or best practices that have emerged lately. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: you can do `<MyComponent --position="absolute" --left="12px">` and it will wrap the component for you, but I personally do not recommend that system.